# Using .NET membership providers to secure WCF SOAP API?

Tags: wcf, authentication, soap, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to leverage the in-built .NET membership providers (SQL provider is the important one) to authenticate and authorize WCF SOAP API calls? i.e. I only want specific registered users (inside the membership provider dB) to be able to consume specific SOAP endpoints. How would one go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate user using the Membership Providers. This authentication can happen in 2 ways

1. Using the [WCF authentication service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx)
2. Creating your own WCF service methods that internally use the Membership provider API

for this the WCF service needs to run in ASP.Net compatibility mode.

Once the user is authentication the next step for you would be to add authorization checks within you WCF service. You can use the RoleProviders method [IsUserInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx) to perform such checks. You can also do url authorization once you have done the above stuff. Url authorization can restrict access to entire service based on the role.

Answer (score 0):

The [CodePlex Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guidelines&referringTitle=Home) site, Authentication and Authorization sections provide sample configs and code that will help you achieve what you're trying to do.